# Check whether this sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have sequences $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ and $b_1, b_2, b_3, \ldots$ . What I know about them, is that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ applies $a_n > 0$ and $b_n > 0$ also $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\ \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{\pi}{A}$$

Now I need to find whether
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{11-C}{n^{(B\ \cdot\ \tfrac{a_n}{b_n})}\ +\ 2C}$$
converges.

I am super confused as why I am given that limit, I can't just take that limit and smash it into that sequence, so what do I do with it and how to I check if this converges? 
Note: A is equal to 3, B and C are equal to 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\ B\cdot\frac{a_n}{b_n}=B\cdot\frac{\pi}{A} > 8$$
Begin with some $N$ $$B\cdot\frac{a_n}{b_n} \ge 2$$

And begin with that $N$
$$0\le\dfrac{11-C}{n^{(B\ \cdot\ \tfrac{a_n}{b_n})}\ +\ 2C}=\dfrac{3}{n^{(B\ \cdot\ \tfrac{a_n}{b_n})}\ +\ 16} \le 3\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}$$
so
$$0\le\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}\ \dfrac{11-C}{n^{(B\ \cdot\ \tfrac{a_n}{b_n})}\ +\ 2C}\le 3\cdot\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}\ \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Because right sum converges
$$\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}\ \dfrac{11-C}{n^{(B\ \cdot\ \tfrac{a_n}{b_n})}\ +\ 2C}$$
converges, and therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\ \dfrac{11-C}{n^{(B\ \cdot\ \tfrac{a_n}{b_n})}\ +\ 2C}$$
converges.

Comment: Thank you!! Really helped me a lot

Comment: I just noticed, there after your "And begin with that N" where you put C values in, in the top we get 11 - C which is 11 - 8 = 3 like you did, but in the bottom how did we get that + 6? Because there is 2C and C is 8, shouldn't it bet 16?

Comment: Yes, you are right. edited solution